# ServiceStack external dependency with ILogger dependency

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack host which depends on an external class which has a constructor of the form

```
public class MyClass(ILogger<MyClass) {}
```

but when I call

```
container.AddSingleton<ISearchEngine, ElasticSearchEngine>();
```

ServiceStack is not resolving ILogger, what can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack.Logging abstraction uses .NET Core's logging provider implementation where you'll end up with the same logging implementation using ServiceStack's logging abstraction:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
}
```

Alternatively you can register your dependency with ASP.NET Core's IOC to access their `ILogger<T>` abstraction directly:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISearchEngine, ElasticSearchEngine>();
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use ILog in MyClass I end up with a ServiceStack dependnency in that DLL where this currently isn't one

Comment: @JanMartin Right though `ILog` exists in the dep and impl-free ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll i.e. a tiny abstraction library.

Comment: good point - any chance it will support trace level logging one day? :) very handy to have 5 levels as you get with ILogger

Comment: @JanMartin Just added [backward compat support for trace logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/bc289628082b86d890445df36018e6efc20c4c65/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Logging/ILog.cs#L125-L190) that's implemented by .NET Core log adapter, falls back to debug in other logging providers that don't implement it. Couldn't change `ILog` as it would be a major breaking change to a core interface which hasn't changed in years. Change available from v4.6.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: the man, the mythz, the legend